# How do I create a Custom Bar chart report in GnuCash?

Tags: gnucash, chart

I'm trying to create a custom bar chart report in GnuCash 2.6.5, similar to the Asset Bar Chart or Liability Bar Chart. What I need is a report that shows the sum of 3 (or more) accounts. Some are Liabilities, some are Assets. Neither of the current Bar Charts work for me as selecting an account of the opposite type causes the report to error or clear my choices and reset back to the default view. I'm selecting each account in the tree from the top level down to the specific accounts I want.

I've tried using the Custom Multicolumn View where I've created one Asset Bar chart with the accounts I want and one Liabilities Bar chart, but that just gives me two different graphs, one for each subgraph that I put into it (Assets Bar chart and Liabilities Bar chart). So, that doesn't seem to be an option either, as it doesn't sum the two together to give me a total.

Yes, I know it seems weird to want to treat certain Assets and certain Liabilities as both positive values, but I have a weird setup where as long as the sum of those accounts stays above a certain level gets me other benefits, so being able to track that sum over time helps me make sure I keep that going.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an XSLT transformation to turn the Gnucash file into a Gnumeric file and then plot that in Gnumeric.

http://web.archive.org/web/20070219085556/http://edseek.com/archives/2005/08/18/gnucash-export-to-gnumeric-and-csv/

Yes, it's not very elegant but it should get the job done.Alternatively, export gnumeric to CVS and plot the data with gnuplot.

Comment: Yes, that isn't very elegant, but is one way to do it. I'm trying to see how hard it is to write a report using Scheme to take in accounts as options as well as a threshold value so that I can use those two pieces of data to retrieve and color the graph.